# Some audio files are not playing using AVPlayer swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

**I have 3 remote mp3 files to stream using AVPlayer**

**File 1 - Meta Data (Worked smoothly)**

**File 2 - Meta Data (Still showing as loading, not working ios but worked in android)**

**File 3 - Meta Data (This file is atleast playing something but no playback controls activated like seek, rewind, forward, backward, duration)**

Find meta result here
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1mvHGa6iPJba_Bv6NiYzTpwgHTRGHHd7J

**This is the code i have implemeted**

```
let destinationString = "https://example.com/audio.mp3"
let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: destinationString)
player = AVPlayer(url:fileUrl)
let vc = AVPlayerViewController()
vc.showsPlaybackControls = true
vc.player = player
self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
self.addChildViewController(vc)
player.play()
```

Searched a lot for supported file types and content types but doesn't get any relevant result even from apple documentation , Have anybody encountered this issue before ?

**Totally helpless.**
Please help me.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Are you sure that these files are actually mp3s? Only the second of your links still gives me a result, but from the information available there (especially the codec), this may be a 3gp file, not an mp3. To my experience AVAsset can be a bit picky about the (file-) extensions, so you may want to make sure they're correct.

Comment: I'm not sure because i don't what encoding parameter is actually needed for fulfill an MP3

Comment: PS: Meta result updated please check the new link

Answer (score 1):

Try using string init for URL

```
let fileUrl = URL(string: destinationString)!
```

Something to start with. If this does not work try playing those files on your iPhone's safari. If it works then there is something wrong within the app else it could be a server issue.

At least this will help you debug the issue

Comment: Thank you for your support.  I've already tried like this URL(string: destinationString)! but happens the same thing.

Comment: Even player.error does not throwing an error. So lost hope on runtime log

Comment: Heyy did you find a solution for this problem?? I am also facing the same issue.